# Keep coordinates under mouse when moving the camera in THREE js

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am trying to keep an object under the mouse cursor when moving the camera around and when zoomed.

I this example i want to keep the mouse cursor over the red circle when moving the camera around http://codepen.io/madalinul/pen/bebgjZ?editors=0110

I tried some random number and with this code it works ok at high zoom levels but when I zoom out it doesn't.

```
//19 is max zoom level
var zoomFactor = 19 - zoomLevel;
    var moveFactor = (0.007 * (1 + zoomFactor));
    lon = (onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX) * moveFactor + onPointerDownLon;
    lat = (event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY) * moveFactor + onPointerDownLat;
  }
```

From my test it also depends on the renderer size. Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to use use ray casting technique,get the current cursor position,place the camera there and then begin to zoom.You also need to transfer 3 co-ordinate to 2 co-ordinate.